# Perform mathematical operation on a matching columns from 2 data frames: Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, frame

I have these two data frames with different row indices but some columns are same.
What I want to do is to a get a data frame that sums the numbers of the two data frames with same column names

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1,2,3),(3,4,5),(5,6,7)], columns=['a','b','d'], index = ['A', 'B','C','D'])
df1
   a  b  d
A  1  2  3
B  3  4  5
C  5  6  7

df2 = pd.DataFrame([(10,20,30)], columns=['a','b','c'])

df2
    a   b   c
0  10  20  30
```

Output dataframe:

```
    a   b  d
A  11  22  3
B  13  24  5
C  15  16  7
```

Whats the best way to do this?   .add() doesn't seem to work with data frames with different indices.

Comment: The problem here is that alignment will occur column and index-wise. Do you care how to arrive at the final df? I mean this works: `pd.DataFrame(data=(df1.values + df2.values), columns = df2.columns, index = df1.index)`

Comment: If I'm not wrong you `df1` has `a,b,d` columns and `df2` has `a,b,c` columns. And, when you add, you want only `a,b` common columns to be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one-liner does the trick:

```
In [30]: df1 + df2.ix[0].reindex(df1.columns).fillna(0)
Out[30]:
    a   b  d
A  11  22  3
B  13  24  5
C  15  26  7
```

Comment: Ah. the `reindex` +1 for the one-liner

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

Extract common columns on which you want to add from `df1` and `df2`.

```
In [153]: col1 = df1.columns

In [154]: col2 = df2.columns

In [155]: cols = list(set(col1) & set(col2))

In [156]: cols
Out[156]: ['a', 'b']
```

And, now add the values

```
In [157]: dff = df1

In [158]: dff[cols] = df1[cols].values+df2[cols].values

In [159]: dff
Out[159]:
    a   b  d
A  11  22  3
B  13  24  5
C  15  26  7
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the shortest approach:

```
In [36]:

print df1 + df2.ix[0,df1.columns].fillna(0)
    a   b  d
A  11  22  3
B  13  24  5
C  15  26  7
```

Step 1 result a `series` like this:
    In [44]:

```
df2.ix[0,df1.columns]
Out[44]:
a    10
b    20
d   NaN
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

fill the `nan` and added it to `df1` will suffice, as the index will be aligned:

```
In [45]:

df2.ix[0,df1.columns].fillna(0)
Out[45]:
a    10
b    20
d     0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Check the OP's `d column` output.